# get an array of doubles from a an array within a custom object in a map

Tags: java-8

I have a custom object (Allocation) in a Map. I am looking to get the column of weights for each Allocation entry in the map. For example if I have 10 Map entries and each Allocation object has 3 weights, I would like to get the ith weight of each Map entry in Java 8. Here is an example of what I am looking for. Any ideas or suggestions to do this in Java 8. Thank you!

```
key: portfolio1, Object: (risk=0.03, weights={0.3,0.2,0.5}, returnvalue=0.5)
Key: portfolio2, Object: (risk=0.05, weights={0.4,0.4,0.2}, returnvalue=0.3)
Key: portfolio3, Object: (risk=0.01, weights={0.5, 0.25, 0.25}, return=0.6)
```

if the above 3 Portfolios are 3 Map entries, I would like to get the weights from each of the 3 Portfolios in an array as:

```
 first column of weights as

weight[0]=0.3 from portfolio 1
weight[1] = 0.4 from portfolio 2
weight[2] = 0.5 from portfolio 3
```

second column of weights as:

```
weight[0] = 0.2 from portfolio 1
weight[1] = 0.4 from portfolio 2
weight[2] = 0.25 from portfolio 3



public class Allocation {
private double returnValue;
private double risk;
private double[] weights;

public Allocation() {
    returnValue = 0;
    risk = 0;
    weights = null;
}

public double getReturnValue() {
    return returnValue;
}

public void setReturnValue(double returnValue) {
    this.returnValue = returnValue;
}

public double getRisk() {
    return risk;
}

public void setRisk(double risk) {
    this.risk = risk;
}

public double[] getWeights() {
    return weights;
}

public void setWeights(double[] weights) {
    this.weights = weights;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done so far in a solution with Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Allocation> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("portfolio1", a1);
map.put("portfolio2", a2);
map.put("portfolio3", a3);

// Calculate max size of the weights array. Can be omitted if you already know the size.
int maxNumberOfWeights = map.values()
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(allocation -> allocation.getWeights().length)
        .max()
        .getAsInt();

// List of list of columns
List<List<Double>> result = IntStream.range(0, maxNumberOfWeights)
        .mapToObj(idx -> map.values()
                .stream()
                .map(Allocation::getWeights)
                .map(doubles -> doubles.length > idx ? doubles[idx] : 0) // can be just .map(doubles -> doubles[idx]) if the length of all weights arrays will always be the same
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
[[0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.25], [0.5, 0.2, 0.25]]
```

Or to have `double[]`s instead, you can do:

```
List<double[]> result = IntStream.range(0, maxNumberOfWeights)
        .mapToObj(idx -> map.values()
                .stream()
                .map(Allocation::getWeights)
                .mapToDouble(doubles -> doubles.length > idx ? doubles[idx] : 0)
                .toArray())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(doubles -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubles)));
```

**Output**

```
[0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
[0.2, 0.4, 0.25]
[0.5, 0.2, 0.25]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function in your class

```
public double getWeightByIndex(int i){
    return weights[i];
}
```

Now say you have an arraylist of Portfolios and presumably all of them have the same column length then

```
ArrayList<double[]> result = new ArrayList<double[]>();
for(int i=0; i<allocationList[0].length; i++){//for each column
    double arr[] = new double[allocationList[0].length];
    for(Allocation a : allocationList){
        arr[i] = a.get(i).getWeightByIndex(i)  
    }
    result.add(arr);
}
```

At the end of it you should have an arraylist of array by corresponding index.

I used an arraylist because i do not know your object definition but it will produce the output you require

i.e. `weight = result.get(1)` will produce

```
weight[0] = 0.3 
weight[1] = 0.4 
weight[2] = 0.5
```

Comment: He has asked for JAVA -8

Comment: @KunalVohra this _is_ java 8. Perhaps you/OP are asking for _Stream API_.

Comment: Do let me know why it is not java 8 though.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for pointing out. Careless mistake on my part as i couldn't reproduce the question so it was not tested. But why was it non java-8?

Comment: Well, I agree with Kartik, this *is* Java 8. It’s not actively using the newest features, but that’s not a requirement.

Comment: @Holger Oh i see! Thanks for pointing out the errors. I was wandering because someone earlier than you also commented something implying it isn't java-8. Have a great day!